# HTML - Redirect; if timeout, redirect another

Tags: html, redirect, meta-tags, http-redirect

To simply redirect we can use:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='https://www.example.com'" />
```

Say there is a new but buggy website `buggy.example.com` that sometimes down, and a old but stable alternative `stable.example.com`.

How can I set a timeout, like 1 second, if it reaches the limit (possibly down) then redirect to another site?

Using two `meta` tags does not seems to work.

```html
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='https://buggy.example.com'" />
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; url='https://stable.example.com'" />
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out using javascript:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href = "https://stable.example.com";
    }, 1000);
    window.location.href = "https://buggy.example.com";
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```